# Make QtQuick/QML app respect http_proxy variable?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm working through [*Getting Started with Qt Quick*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01B9DV54G), which contains many examples that retrieve resources remotely. Here's one (from Chapter 5.1) that downloads a font from the web:

```
import QtQuick 2.6                                                                                                                                                                                              
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 250
    height: 100

    FontLoader {
        id: myFont
        source: "http://qmlqb.tk/downloads/ds-digi.ttf"
    }

    Text {
        id: myText
        anchors.fill: parent
        font.family: myFont.name
        font.pointSize: 24
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        text: "Hello, World!"
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, I'm running these examples from behind a draconian firewall that requires authentication, and only permits connections to remote hosts on port 80/443. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17821358/99127) provided a workaround that I'm not entirely happy with. The above example works fine if I patch its boilerplate `main.cpp` like so:

```
--- main.cpp.orig   2016-12-05 17:26:20.941009088 -0500
+++ main.cpp    2016-12-05 17:26:26.585009088 -0500
@@ -1,12 +1,21 @@
 #include <QGuiApplication>
 #include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
+#include <QNetworkProxy>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

+    QNetworkProxy proxy;
+    proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy);
+    proxy.setHostName("10.234.56.78");
+    proxy.setPort(8080);
+    proxy.setUser("stickyjoe");
+    proxy.setPassword("s3kr3tpAsswd");
+    QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);
+
     QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
     engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

     return app.exec();
 }
```

But... it appears that I need to do this for *every single* example, which is a little frustrating. I'd much prefer to simply set the `http_proxy` / `https_proxy` variables, as suggested in the previously-referenced question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17828861/99127).

Alas, it doesn't work. If I type `export http_proxy='http://stickyjoe:s3kr3tpAsswd@10.234.56.78:8080/'` in a terminal and then launch `qtcreator` manually from there, the example *still* prints "Hello, World!" in the default font instead of the one from http://qmlqb.tk/downloads/ds-digi.ttf. I also clicked around extensively in *Projects -> Build & Run* from within Qt Creator to make doubly sure the variable was set in both the *Build* and *Run* environments. It was, but... the app still seemed to ignore it entirely.

Is there some way to force a QtQuick/QML app to honor the `http_proxy` variable so that I don't have to patch every example?

Comment: The answer you are linking to is for the web view element, so that variable could be webkit specific.

Comment: Hmm, no, that looks like it should also apply to general proxy handling: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/network/kernel/qnetworkproxy_generic.cpp.html#_ZN20QNetworkProxyFactory19systemProxyForQueryERK18QNetworkProxyQuery

Comment: @KevinKrammer, yeah, it looks like setting `http_proxy` *should* work, but... it definitely isn't in my case. It's possible that I'm (somehow) Doing It Wrong™, but I can't see how. I even tried running the example in Qt 5.7 (even though the book targets 5.6) to see whether it made a difference, but got the same result: the custom font failed to download when I set `http_proxy` in the environment, but it works fine if I manually add the proxy setup code in `main.cpp`.

Comment: It seems the system proxy is either not set or overwritten. Probably would need some debugging to see why the reading of the env variables isn't reached